# What is the boost way to determine if the given path contains a path delimiter?

Tags: c++, boost, path

I have a `boost::filesystem::path` instance `x`. I would like to determine whether `x` contains any path delimiters in it.

Now, I can simply look for `\\` and `/` in `x.string()`, but I am interested in the boost way to do it, meaning utilizing the `boost::filesystem` library, if possible.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

1. Let me narrow the problem space. My tool is never going to be run on anything, but the Windows OS.
2. I have forgotten the drive specifications (`c:`, etc...). I do not want them either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.**

But do you really want to? For example `c:a` contains two path elements `c:` and `a` on windows. Why do you need to search for a path delimiter? What makes you think that such a thing exists on all platforms? What is a path delimiter in OpenVMS? E.g. in:

```
[a.b.c]a.txt;12
```

Morale: paths are more complicated beasts than people are used to think. And in fact `boost::filesystem::path` doesn't work well anywhere beyond POSIX paths. But this is another story.

**EDIT:** assuming that your question is how to check if a path consists of a single element then the answer is, well, count the number of elements:

```
boost::filesystem::path p = ...;
if(std::distance(p.begin(), p.end()) == 1)
    cout << "one element\n";
```

Comment: @mark: your question didn't became clearer. Do you mean "how to check whether a path has more than one path element"?

Comment: Why not? Take a path. If it contains a path delimiter or a drive specification, then it is not good for me. For instance, these are all bad inputs - "c:aaa", "aaaa\\", "\\aaa".

Comment: @mark: 'good' and 'bad' aren't mathematically well defined. See the edit.